# does azure notification hub work with raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, azure-notificationhub

I'm hoping that I can catch some smart raspberry pi hobbyist out there.  I am wanting to use azure notification hub to push messages out to a raspberry pi.  I'm wondering what options are available and the pro/con of each approach.

I know that with the pi, I can easily run python scripts.  Can I use python to register and receive the notifications?  or am I looking at something more esoteric like mono or java?

Answer (score 0):

Notification Hubs does not currently support Push messaging TO Raspberry Pi devices. Azure Notification Hubs currently supports Push notifications through many of the major PNS providers (Google, Apple, Amazon, Windows) and continues to expand it's coverage of those push services. When/If the Raspberry Pi

However, if you want to trigger a push notification to a mobile device from the Raspberry Pi, there are a set of REST APIs that are available that you should be able to call from your language of choice. You can find more details on the REST APIs at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530746.aspx)